# Adding content to Prototype Cell causes cellForRowAtIndexPath to loop endlessly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I have a UITableViewController subclass as a scene in my storyboard.

I'm trying to configure a Prototype Cell, but when I add any elements to the cell's content view, running the app causes `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to get called endlessly. If I remove the elements (like a UILabel, for example) and just let an empty, custom prototype cell load, everything is fine. If I change the type of cell from Custom to Basic, everything works fine.

Here's my setup:

```
Storyboard: MyStorboard.storyboard
Scene: 
  MyScene1
    Paging UIScrollView (adds 5 UITableViewControllers to itself) like so:
      UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard story...Name:@"MyStoryboard"];

      // myTVC is another scene "floating" (no transitions) that I will call by id
      MyTVC *myTVC = [storyboard instantiate...Identifier:@"myTableView"];
      (addChildVC, addSubview, didMoveToParent)
      ...

      In MyTVC#cellForRowAtIndexPath:
      MyTVCell *cell = [tableView dequeue...Identifier:@"MyCell"];

      // this log statement will print out endlessly until I kill the app
      NSLog(@"cell: %@ %p", cell, cell);
      return cell;
```

Again, in my storyboard, if I have any content at all in my subclass of MyTVCell, the app will loop endlessly. If I remove all content, empty cells render fine and as expected.

**UPDATE**

Adding debug screenshot at commenter's request:

[image]

Comment: pastebin all your code

Comment: @KlevisonMatias, here's the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/z88iuLa3. Thanks. Let me know if you need more context. I didn't not include storyboard xml.

Comment: 1) Using storyboard deque cell using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`. Your code:  `MyTVCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyTVCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];` 2) Put a breakpoint alt `return cell` and open the "show the debug navigator" tab (xcode) to see who is calling cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: 2 - [UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:], 1 - [NSObject(TLDelegateSW) tisw_tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:], 0 - [MyTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]

Comment: uploaded screenshot. not sure how helpful it will be since it's so small

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74595/discussion-between-djibouti33-and-klevison-matias).

Comment: So aprove my answer.